# Import List from backup to different collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to import a list I exported to a different site collection using PowerShell. I am using the Import-SPWeb but I can't seem to direct it the site collection I want.

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://site/projects/abc/Lists -path "c:\temp\List\IssuesList.cmp"
```

It returns an error:

```
Import-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPWeb object with Id or Url : http://site/
projects/abc/Lists.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I was trying to go directly to the site's list collection instead of going just to the site itself. The site knows where it's lists are.

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://site/projects/abc -path "c:\temp\List\IssuesList.cmp"
```